# MySQL subtracting multiple times for same row in update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table of comments and a table of posts

Whenever a post is deleted, a query runs to subtract the number of comments (that are deleted later) from each user's comment_count

So if a user has 2 comments in a post, and that post is deleted, their balance should have 2 subtracted from it

My query is as follows:

```
    UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN comment ON users.id = comment.author 
       SET comment_count = comment_count - 1 
     WHERE comment.post = 1
```

User A has 2 comments with .post = 1, but for some reason that user only gets comment_count subtracted by 1 once, when it should happen twice

I think my syntax is right because when I:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM users 
INNER JOIN comment ON users.id = comment.author 
     WHERE comment.post = 1
```

I get two results for user A

Shouldn't `UPDATE` be iterating over those two results, subtracting each time?

Can someone explain what I am missing? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to store the count, use:

```
UPDATE USERS
   SET comment_count = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                          FROM COMMENT c
                         WHERE c.author = USERS.id)
```

...or:

```
UPDATE USERS u
  JOIN (SELECT c.author,
               COUNT(*) AS numComments
          FROM COMMENT c
      GROUP BY c.author) x ON x.author = u.id
   SET comment_count = x.numComments
```

There's no point in relying on two records to subtract twice, when you could perform the operation once.

I prefer not to store such values, because they can be calculated based on records without the hassle of keeping the counts in sync.  A [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) might be a better idea...

Comment: +1 Good answer, didnt know the exact MySQL syntax, so I waited for you to answer X-)

Comment: also they can be maintained by triggers. Btw, `COUNT(*)` in real time is almost always expensive (i.e. when you need to "sort by comments" - to get the most popular publications).

Comment: @zerkms: I try not to use triggers if I don't have to, which next to impossible on MySQL :)

Comment: don't agree ;-) `SELECT` is in 90% of applications is much more frequent type of query, than data modification queries. So for me trigger is a better (cheaper) solution.

Comment: the reason I am storing counts is because this will be a high volume script, and that count may be queried 10 or more times on a page, i figure it would be much faster to store the values instead of making the relationships for each query